# Is there any way to map columns in a database in android like EJB entities?

Tags: android, jakarta-ee

For those of you who are familiar with EJB and Android. I've started working on an android project where I need persistent data. The projects I develop at work revolve around using EJB web services and I have grown fond of how EJB maps entities to database columns for you. Is there a solution in android that is similar? (I couldn't think of the term that describes that, sorry)

What I really wanted was to use SOAP web services with EJB but I just couldn't get the ksoap lib to work so I'm trying to explore options. Ideally I'd like to store the data on a remote server but local files on the user's phone wouldn't be the end of the world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure more convenient than the default solution would be to use ORM combined with some library for JSON serialization (I find json and REST somewhat more convenient that SOAP), this is the usual combination I use.

- For ORM I have used with success [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)
- For JSON serialziation / deserialization I recommend [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: ORM does appear to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks!